# Getting error while retrieving value from dropdown

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsp

I have a made a simple `jsp` page which just includes a single dropdown page jsut for testing purposes . i have put a small condition in the dropdown but it is not running with the condition

the code is as follows

```
<html>
<body>
    <form method="get" name="form">  
    <select name="color">
        <option value="empty">Select Color</option>
        <option value="a">red</option>
        <option value="b">blue</option>
        <option value="c">green</option>
        <option value="d">yellow</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>

<%  String color = request.getParameter("color");  
    if(color == "empty"){
      out.println("blah blah blah");   
    }
%>
```

nothing gets printed which means the `if` condition is not running 
can somebody help here ?

Comment: your javascript code is never called so nothing will be printed. You may simply wrap it in a function and call the function on some UI event.

Comment: where's your `JavaScript` code ? there's only `html` and `scriplet`..

Comment: @JunedAhsan its inside the `html` , i havnt pasted the full code

Comment: @amol you should post the correct code to get the right help.

Comment: @JunedAhsan i have posted now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think `if(color == "empty")` is how you compare Strings in java.
It should be `if(color.equals("empty"))`

Comment: this is javascript and not java

Comment: Its a scriptlet, so it follows java syntax

Comment: thanks @NikhilTalreja , it is working now , but i have seen the `==` operator used sometimes(working) so thats why i used it here

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code :

```
<select name="color" onchange="getComboA(this)>
    <option value="empty">Select Color</option>
    <option value="a">red</option>
    <option value="b">blue</option>
    <option value="c">green</option>
    <option value="d">yellow</option>
</select>
```

in javascript :

```
<script>
  function getComboA(sel) {
    var value = sel.value;
    if(value == "empty"){
        alert("Blah Blah");
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the scriptlet( code between <%%>) is executed when the page is executed, so with this code, you can't get any parameter because the form wasn't submitted yet...
You can do something like

```
 <select name="color" onchange="printValue(this)">
```

then on some script tag use the value like

```
    function printValue(sel){
      var value = sel.value;
      alert("selected : " + value);
    }
```

or you can try to use the method location.reload(true) or maybe window.location.reload(true); (true to be reloaded from the server)  but I never used this one.